# Simple Determinant explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for a simple, baby explanation as to why when I am computing a determinant I ignore the row and column of my top variables (what does that mean) Why am I allowed to do that?. Please only baby explanations I am trying to understand the intuition/ why it works/its meaning, before tackling the real thing more indepth. Thank you

Example: Given this matrice

$ \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 2\\
   3 & 4  \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

I can find the determinant by eliminating the row of 1 and colum of 1 and then getting 4 which I will multiply by 1.   ab = 4

then I can eliminate row 1 and colum 2 and get   cd = 6.

then I compute 4-6 = -2

thank you for your time.

Comment: with row elimination, you're not losing the influence of the row, you're just "hiding" it in another row

Comment: You seem to be referring to [Laplace Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion).  Some students learn this as the definition for what a determinant is in the first place.  Otherwise, you would have learned of a determinant using the [Leibniz Formula for Determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants).  There is a proof for why Laplace Expansion results in the same end result as the Leibniz Formula in the first link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the following procedure. Suppose we have a matrix \begin{pmatrix}a & c & d\\
e & f & g\\
h & i & j\end{pmatrix}

The simplest approach to evaluating the determinant of this matrix is to expand by the top row, so we take $$a\left|\begin{array}{cc} f & g\\ i & j\end{array}\right|-c\left|\begin{array}{cc} e & g\\ h & j\end{array}\right|+d\left|\begin{array}{cc} e & f\\ h & i\end{array}\right|$$ So the idea is for each element in the top row you delete its row and column and take the determinant of the resulting matrix. Signs alternate. The same idea for a $2\times 2$ matrix such as the first one above gives simply $fj-gi$.

So after doing that we get that the original determinant is $$a(fj-gi)-c(ej-gh)+d(ei-fh)=$$ $$afj-agi-cej+cgh+dei-dfh$$

Notice that we have six terms. In the general case we have $n!$ (why?). Each term has one element from the first row, one from the second, and one from the third. Similarly, it has one element from the first column, one from the second, and one from the third. And it has all such elements with no repetitions.

The pattern of +/- is not so easy to see. You could write the determinant in the general $n\times n$ case as $$\sum_\sigma\left(\text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^na_{i,\sigma_i}\right)$$ where the sum is taken over all permutations $\sigma$ of $123\dots n$ and sgn$(\sigma)$ is the parity of the permutation (+1 for even and -1 for odd).

Why that works, and why you can expand by any row, or any column, and why it gives $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ all requires a certain amount of theory. It also depends on where you are starting from. One can look at determinants from several points of view.

Geometrically, we can think of the rows as representing $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If the determinant is non-zero (or equivalently the matrix is invertible), then if we think of the vectors as directed line segments from the origin, they give the $n$-dimensional version of a parallelepiped, and the determinant gives its signed volume.

Comment: Yeah, I am referring to the fact that in a 2x2 we cancel rows and columns and then in a 3 x 3 we also cancel columns and then use a 2x2 to solve it. I just want to understand why do I cancel the rows and columns. I feel like I am in a loop where I simply cancel a row and colums but do not get the why I have to cancel them. I am trying to get to the prove od det(ab) = det(A)det(b) but I am trying to prove this to get to it.

Comment: Ok, I will add a little more.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this a lot.

Comment: The problem is that a detailed treatment of determinants represents several hours of lectures. I think that is enough to start with.

Comment: I am looking at it right now. Thank you so much for trying to help me understand.